# Why is mouse wheel scrolling gone in a ScrollViewer?

Tags: wpf, treeview, scrollviewer

I am adding a ScrollViewer around my TreeView for 2 reasons:

1. i want more control over the way my TreeView scroll bar looks
2. i want more control over my TreeView scroll bars position, because i want to synchronize a few tree views.

it seems that as soon as i add a ScrollView around TreeView, i lose the ability to scroll it using mouse scroller.

I guess my question is 2 part. Do i gain anything by adding my own ScrollView, and is this behavior by design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think either of your requirements precludes using the `ScrollViewer` that is within the `TreeView` template. You might need to re-template the `TreeView` to achieve your goals.

This also sheds light on why your scrolling doesn't work as expected. You've effectively got a `ScrollViewer` around a `ScrollViewer`. What you would need to do for that to work is either remove the ScrollViewer from the TreeView template, or disable it:

```
<TreeView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ...>
```

That said, I do think the better option in your case may be to re-template/re-style the `TreeView` itself.

Comment: good points.. i did try to disable the vertical scrollviewer visibility but that didn't isn't working so far. i do agree about the other points however.

Answer (score 1):

you can retemplate your treeview to remove the inner scrollviewer

```
<ScrollViewer Height="200" Width="200">
  <TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeView">
              <Border Name="Border"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      CornerRadius="1"
                      BorderThickness="1">
                <ItemsPresenter />
              </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">Test001</TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">Test002</TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">Test003</TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">Test004</TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">Test005</TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">Test006</TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">Test007</TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">Test008</TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">Test009</TreeViewItem>
  </TreeView>
</ScrollViewer>
```